# Add value to Object inside a function from another function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am looking to update the value in a chaseObj from the method in another object. Please Advise, Thank you!

```
var s, searchUts;
var getValue = '';
var generateObject = function() {
  var chaseObj = {
    "timeFilters" : getValue
  };
  return chaseObj;
};

searchUts = s = {
  createValue: function() {
    var x = 10;
    var y = 20;
    getValue = x + y; //append this value to chaseObj inside the generateObject
  },
  postToBackEnd: function() {
  var chaseObj = generateObj();
    $.ajax({
    url: localhost:8080/site/home,
    data:JSON.stringify(chaseObj) //chaseObj is not updated with new value here

    })
  }

};
```

Comment: You could make `timeFilters` a [getter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

Comment: since it's un-reachable though code, you can't. you can pass an object around to keep the refs instead of mere string values, or use a method + closure.

Comment: yes there was a typo

Comment: Didn't get you @dandavis

Comment: can you please advise a snippet @4castle

Comment: `var getValue = [''];` then use `getValue[0] = x + y` insead of `getValue = x + y`, just using  `getValue[0]` everywhere you used `getValue` before; this saves getter function call overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Unclear what you want but is this the result you wanted?

```js
var s, searchUts;
var getValue = '';
var generateObject = function() {
  var chaseObj = {
    "timeFilters" : getValue
  };
  return chaseObj;
};

searchUts = s = {
  createValue: function(obj) {
    var x = 10;
    var y = 20;
    obj.timeFilters = x + y; //append this value to chaseObj inside the generateObject
  },
  postToBackEnd: function() {
     var chaseObj = generateObject();
     this.createValue(chaseObj);
     console.log(JSON.stringify(chaseObj));
  }
};

s.postToBackEnd();
```

Comment: great job! but unfortunately at my end I have multiple params to createValue method and if I use this code, its not working